# Getting "too few arguments to function"

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int powFunc(int, int);

int main() //main function
{
   int x, y, p = 0;

   printf("enter the base no. and the power ");
   scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

   p = powFunc(int x, int y); // Getting an error here

   printf("%d to the power of %d is %d\n",x,y,p);

   return 0;
}

  int powFunc(int base, int n)
  {
      int p;
      for(p = 1; n < 0; n--)
         p = p * base;

      return p;
  }
```

Comment: When you call a function you should not specify the types of the parameters.

Comment: @vedant yawalkar This statement p = powFunc(int x, int y); does not contain a function call. It seems you mean p = powFunc( x, y);

Comment: WRONG: `p = powFunc(int x, int y);`  CORRECT: `p = powFunc(x, y);`.  You only need the type in the declaration, not when you actually make the call.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put data types when you want to use variables as function parameters. Change:

```
p = powFunc(int x, int y);
```

into:

```
p = powFunc(x, y);
```

And also, you made a semantic error here:

```
for (p = 1; n < 0; n--) {
    p = p * base;
}
```

You want to check if `n > 0` not `n < 0`. Correct the logic:

```
p = 1; n > 0; n--
```